# after switching language,fragment will increase duplicate option menu item

Tags: android, internationalization, android-fragments, application-settings, optionmenu

[image]

in v4.fragment, i set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` and then in `onCreateOptionsMenu` i set `inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);`, everything is ok until i switch language.

when the app is running, and i press home-key, open setting, change locale language, select my running app from recently app list, the option menu in actionbar will increase duplicate menuitem, what's happen?

Comment: show activity and fragment source code

Comment: I probably know why .
when i change the locale, the android will recall the onCreate method in the Activity which is showing, unless you set the manifest . in my activity, the fragment will be regenerate and attach to Activity,the old fragment in fragmentmanager and the newly fragment  in the same Activity.So the activity have the duplicate menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gemini,  I know it is late and you most probably have the answer already.  The easiest way to fix this issue is to just add menu.clear();

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

  menu.clear();

  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);
}
```